# Titanium, Can you print a WebView webpage

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

In Titanium, is it possible to print a webpage, similar to printing a webpage from Safari? I'm using WebView.

It only needs to work with iOS, not Android.

If so, how? I haven't been able to find anything about this. One person told me it was impossible, but I thought I'd ask Stackoverflow - people here often surprise me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the toImage() function on the WebView it takes a print to the visible area:

`$.webview.toImage();`

You want all the html content right?

If not, an possible workaround (I've didn't try this), but in order to do this, you need to know the html document height.

Create another WebView on an lower zIndex of your content app or place it out of the visible area like:

`$.webview2.left = Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth;`

Take a print of that copied WebView with:

`$.webview2.toImage();`

Than remove that view, obviously this wont work for all situations.

Comment: Yes, I'd create webpage such that the whole area was to be printed. And then this image can just be printed to whatever printer is linked to the iPhone/iPad? You're my hero!

Comment: Can you print the image directly from the app, or will it need to be saved to the device first and printed from there?

Comment: If you use the toImage function, it takes a picture of the view that calls that function.

It returns an image, you can do whatever you want with it, set as an image of a ImageView, backgroundImage of a View or save it to app directory.

Comment: Once I've used this to print my app main window with all content and share in social networks with a Titanium Social Module, and to use as image files in apps store.

Comment: After converting the view.toImage() what should be the function that I must use to print the image? any idea please